# C#_Timer/Stopwatch unable to continue from time extracted from database

Tags: c#, sql, timer, stopwatch

I have below code to start and stop timer/stopwatch and load value into database.
The stopwatch works fine, and time is able to load into database and extract from database into textbox.

the problem is after i extract the time from database and insert into text box, then i start timer, it didnt start from current time. It always start from 0.
there is no error when running the program.

Could anyone help for troubleshoot please? Thanks in advance!

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
    String SNconnectionstring = (@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SNDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
    DispatcherTimer dtSN = new DispatcherTimer();
    Stopwatch swSN = new Stopwatch();
    string currentTimeSN = string.Empty;

   public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SNCreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConSN = new SqlConnection(SNconnectionstring))
        {
            sqlConSN.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmdSN = new SqlCommand("SNadd", sqlConSN);
            sqlCmdSN.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmdSN.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SN", sNtxtbox.Text);
            sqlCmdSN.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", SNTime.Text.Trim());
            sqlCmdSN.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

private void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConSN = new 
SqlConnection(SNconnectionstring))
        {
            sqlConSN.Open();

            String sqlSelectQuerySN = ("Select * FROM tblSN WHERE SN = @SN");
            SqlCommand sqlCmdSNLoad = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectQuerySN, sqlConSN);
            sqlCmdSNLoad.Parameters.Add("@SN", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sNtxtbox.Text;
            SqlDataReader drSNReader = sqlCmdSNLoad.ExecuteReader();               
            if (drSNReader.Read())
            {
                SNTime.Text = (drSNReader["Time"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                SNTime.Text = "";
            }
         }
 private void sNbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl.SelectedIndex = 1;
        dtSN.Tick += new EventHandler(dtSN_Tick);
        dtSN.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);   
    }

    void dtSN_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (swSN.IsRunning)
        {
            TimeSpan tsSN = swVASN.Elapsed;
            currentTimeSN = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", tsSN.Hours, tsSN.Minutes, tsSN.Seconds);
            txtSN.Text = currentTimeSN;
        }
    }
    private void btnTimeStartSN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        swSN.Start();
        dtSN.Start();
    }

    private void btnTimeStopSN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (swSN.IsRunning)
        {
            swSN.Stop();
        }

    }
```

Comment: of course the timer starts from 0, what's the problem with it? Also you say that you start the timer after you paste the time from the db into your textbox, but you don't. you only set the textbox, nothing else

Comment: it looks like it should set currentTimeVASN to @Time?

Comment: I changed the code to, but still didnt fix the issue. looks weird: void dtVASN_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (swVASN.IsRunning) { TimeSpan tsVASN = swVASN.Elapsed; txtVASN.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", tsVASN.Hours, tsVASN.Minutes, tsVASN.Seconds); } }

Comment: I'm sorry but your naming convention is so confusing that I can't help you. I don't even understand what exactly your problem is, because it doesn't seem like a problem at all..

Comment: My appologies for confusion. I have just edited the code, hope it is now easier to understand.  I think i might have understand the cause of the issue which could be txtSN.Text only equal to currentTimeSN which start from 0 and didnt start from existing time extracted from database. I just now tried a few way to add existing time from database, but didnt succeed.